# Screen rendering issue 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, fonts

On non fullscreen windows I started to notice missing characters on the title bar and then more generally in the window content itself. Concerned I restarted my laptop and (so far) I have not seen the same issues.

[image: font rendering issue in android studio]

Notice the characters in the title bar are missing.

[image: font rendering issue in screenshot tool]

I'm happy to raise a bug but don't really know for what package or how to go about collecting better information.

1. <del>Should I be concerned given that after a restart I haven't noticed this again?</del>
2. If so what info should I collect before I raise a bug?

Edit: It's happened again. OK really need help with this one now. You can see how frustrating this is.

[image: font rendering issue in software update tool]

Any ideas on where to start collecting bug information? Is this a Unity thing?

Comment: I never had this problem, but it looks like a driver issue. What is the graphic card that you use and which driver?

Comment: I'm using a NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] and it is using the NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.42 from nvidia-361 (proprietary, tested)..... at least this is what the Additional Drivers tool tells me.